# How to stop recording voice automatically after person stops speaking in Android?

Tags: android, speech-to-text, avspeechsynthesizer

I am new to android and trying to build an android application with speech to text. I am following the tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-speech-to-text-tutorial/.

When I click on mic button, It starts recording but stops only after 20 seconds and doesn't stops like it does in Google Now. How can I achieve that?

The speech recording part is:

```
private void promptSpeechInput() {
  Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
  intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
  intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
  intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,
            getString(R.string.speech_prompt));
  try {
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT);
  } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                getString(R.string.speech_not_supported),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding  `EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS` to the intent.  This says how many milliseconds of silence is needed to make it assume input is done.